# Docker responses with `404 page not found` while accessing to 80 port of the container

Tags: docker

I have an issue with connecting to host's 80 port binded to a container.

I run a container with the command `docker run -p 80:80 -d dockerbogo/docker-nginx-hello-world`.

`docker ps` output:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                     COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                               NAMES
b86bd5862016   dockerbogo/docker-nginx-hello-world       "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   18 seconds ago   Up 18 seconds   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, :::80->80/tcp   condescending_elgamal
```

`docker inspect b86bd5862016` output:

```
...
"Ports": {
    "80/tcp": [
        {
            "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
            "HostPort": "80"
        },
        {
            "HostIp": "::",
            "HostPort": "80"
        }
    ]
},
...
"Networks": {
    "bridge": {
        "IPAMConfig": null,
        "Links": null,
        "Aliases": null,
        "NetworkID": "a33eee6b1f1479bef1d9247823a1da0abfc5fc45d1c9e118201f96b05a2959ce",
        "EndpointID": "43c08893ef259d09b8fd0388af1b6a7161c209f10bb7e5143b8625c97ed91267",
        "Gateway": "172.26.0.1",
        "IPAddress": "172.26.0.2",
        "IPPrefixLen": 16,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:1a:00:02",
        "DriverOpts": null
    }
}
...
```

Expected behaviour: `curl localhost` from inside a container or `curl 172.26.0.2` (container IP) from host I get nginx page hello world.

**Not expected behaviour: `curl localhost` from a host I get `404 page not found`.**

Moreover if I run `docker run -p 81:80 -d dockerbogo/docker-nginx-hello-world` and `curl localhost:81` from host I get nginx hello world page as expected.

Why port 80 on host machine is not working?
The problem is somewhere between host network and container network I guess.

I'm runing out of ideas what else I can check?